# Trying to put in values or leave the cell blank

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to put in a formula that puts the cell at yes, no or blank. I tried the following, but received errors:

```
=IF((I5<=J5),"Y","N"),OR(ISBLANK(J5),ISBLANK(K9))
```

I can get the yes/no portion, I just can't figure out the leave blank portion. I'm using microsoft excel for MAC 2011.

[Excel formula on Microsoft Excel for MAC 2011](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8M4F.png)

Comment: Can you describe the logic in plain words? The (wrong) formula does not help. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the k9 cell to have one of three items based on what is in cell j5: yes, no, or blank. if cell i5 is greater than or equal to j5 then cell k9 is populated with a YES, if it is less than j5 it is populated with a NO and if it is blank then k9 is BLANK. The yes,no formula works: =IF((I6<=J6), "Y", "N") but I can't seem to figure out how to add the blank part of the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to leave the cell in column K blank if J5 is blank, other wise compare J5 to I5. If so, the formula is

=if(isblank(J5),"",if(I5<=J5,"Y","N"))

Answer (score 0):

IF statements are Boolean, which means that they can only have one of two outcomes.

What you need is the Excel equivalent of a case statement, which uses clumsily nested IF statements, e.g, try something like:

IF(I5<=J5,"Y",IF(J5>I5,"N",IF(???,"")))

The three question-marks mean that I can't figure out what your third condition is (I5<=J5 is as Boolean is it gets, and ISBLANK doesn't insert a blank, it asks if a cell is blank).